# Detect framed video content using python

Tags: python, opencv, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

I would like to detect framed video content (frequently used in TV advertising and referred to as single split, program split etc.)

**Example 1:**

[image]

**Example 2 (3 screen captures, 2 seconds offset):**

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have the video sequence as well as 3 screen captures available to analyze (middle, middle between middle and end, end).

To get started, I already tried a few methods like bounding box detection, and autocrop algorithms on the screen captures using opencv, imagemagick and PIL. This works to some extent, but not reliably.

- Every TV station uses their own artwork for the surrounding frame
- They sometimes animate the surrounding frame in the first few seconds
- The background of the surrounding frame can be static but also animated, changing colors, etc

What would be an effective method to get a rather precise true/false reading on the media examples above? I would appreciate some ideas to build a suitable algorithm.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the middle and last frames to share with us please? Also, is the background static - I mean is the purple area (in this example) changing continuously between frames?

Comment: Hi Mark, see my updated question. Thanks

Comment: Do you have higher quality images - i.e. bigger and maybe PNG or TIFF rather than JPEG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are essentially looking for two static, horizontal lines and two static, vertical lines that represent the edges of the inset video clip. What is inside the frame and what is outside the frame may/will be changing - only the edges of the inset frame are constant.

I would be applying a strong directional filter (Sobel) oriented at 0 and 90 degrees to find the horizontal and vertical lines. Then work through some number of frames accumulating all the edges that the two filters find. The brightest lines in the image at the end should be the best defined ones that have stayed still the longest.